# Optional image into my model return me Hashable error

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, photo-picker

I'm trying to add `Image?` on my data model in SwiftUI project for add this image into my array of data with the new PhotoPicker announced on WWDC22.

It returns me this error message:

> Type 'RecipeModel' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

> Stored property type 'Image?' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable', preventing
> synthesized conformance of 'RecipeModel' to 'Hashable'

```
struct RecipeModel: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    static func ==(lhs: RecipeModel, rhs: RecipeModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.formImage == rhs.formImage
    }

    var id = UUID()
    let image: String
    var formImage: Image?
    let name: String
    let recipeType: RecipeType
    let timeToCook: Int
    let averagePrice: RecipeAveragePrice
    let difficulty: RecipeDifficulty
    let ingredients: [String]
    let description: String

}

enum RecipeType: String, CaseIterable {
    case entry = "Entrée"
    case dish = "Plat"
    case dessert = "Dessert"
}

enum RecipeAveragePrice: String {
    case cheap = "Économique"
    case medium = "Moyen"
    case expensive = "Cher"
}

enum RecipeDifficulty: String {
    case easy = "Facile"
    case medium = "Moyenne"
    case hard = "Difficile"
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI Image is not a model type, it is view type, so it is bad idea to put it there.

Comment: use `UIImage` not `Image` in a model

Comment: You could conform to Hashable manually